# How can I encode a video for my non-square pixel display?

Tags: ffmpeg, pixels, aspect-ratio

My car stereo has a 800x480 display but is physically 16x9 so I believe it uses non-square pixels.  The documentation says it says (2 400x480) so I think it's describing a 2:1 pixel aspect ratio (?).

If so, how can I convert videos to use the entire resolution of the display?

For example, let's say I have a 720p or 1080p video that I want to encode at 800x480 but make sure it's correctly translating the pixel aspect ratio, etc.

Comment: Seen this yet? [Scaling (resizing) with ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

You state that your display is physically 16:9, which should produce no distortion upon setting the aspect ratio to 16:9.

To set the aspect ratio, use the `-aspect` flag. For example, to set an aspect ratio of 16:9, in the encoding parameters use:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile ...other parameters... -aspect 16:9... outputfile
```

**Note**: The normal 800x480 display is 1.66 and not 1.77. In which case you can't use the **entire** screen area and get an undistorted image because they are different aspect ratios. So there has to be some mask/band of black to compensate for that change- 1.77 to 1.66. Or there will be some cropping.

Comment: What about irregular (non-square) pixels?